# XML extra content error

Tags: xml

I've just started my course and having trouble on this first exercise to do with XML. I was given this code to fix.

```
<title highlight=yes>Computing in 2017</TITLE>
<date>27/09/2013</date>
```

I thought the first line would be fixed like this

```
<title highlight="yes">Computing in 2017</title>
```

I have no idea what's wrong with the date line, but I get the error saying that there is extra content at the end of the document. Any help would be much appreciated sorry if this question is too obvious but I couldn't figure it out myself.

Comment: We probably need more information about the XML - do you have an XSD you are validating against?

Comment: Provide the entire XML document.  That error is very likely to do with a line after what you have shown us (probably near the closing line for the document root element).  If this is actually the whole document, then the problem is that there are two root elements when there can be only one.  In that case, enclose the whole thing in some root element.

Comment: Ah yes this is the entire document by the way, they were the only lines given. How would I go about enclosing the entire thing in a root element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attribute values must be surrounded by single or double quotes.  Case matters in tag names, so `<title>` must be closed with `</title>`, not `</TITLE>`.  You've already resolved those two problems.

The remaining problem is that XML documents must have exactly one root element in order to be well-formed.  Yours has two.  Either eliminate one, or wrap both in a single element:

```
<r>
  <title highlight="yes">Computing in 2017</title>
  <date>27/09/2013</date>
</r>
```